# Detecting line breaks in java

Tags: java

I'm writing a huffman tree and I need to know the frequencies of line breaks and spaces.

Using `Scanner` or `InputStreamReader`, is there anyway to store sentences with line breaks and spaces into a single String?

If I have the code below,

```
public class HuffmanTreeApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HuffTree theTree = new HuffTree();
        System.out.print("sentence: ");
        String get;
        get = getString();
    }
    public static String getString() throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String s = br.readLine();
        return s;
    }
    public static char getChar() throws IOException {
        String s = getString();
        return s.charAt(0);
    }
    public static int getInt() throws IOException {
        String s = getString();
        return Integer.parseInt(s);
    }
}
```

and if my **input** is

```
"you are               
good";
```

then I wanna store all the characters including line breaks and spaces into this one string variable **get**.  So in this case, there will be one line break and one space.

Is this possible?

Comment: How are your sentences separated? If you can identify a delimiter regex (e.g. `"[!?;.]\s+"`?), [`useDelimiter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter%28java.util.regex.Pattern%29) together with [`next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) is your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using readLine (which reads characters until it finds a new line character, and then discard it), use read(char[], offset, len), which will capture new lines as well.

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
char [] buf = new char[0xff];

while(br.read(buf, 0, 0xff))
{
    sb.append(new String(buf, "utf-8"));
}

String result = sb.toString();
```

Comment: I have never used this method before. Can you give me an example of using it? I read the java.docs on it but am still not sure how to use it.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a school that teaches you. Did you try searching net? And what is wrong with ... just **trying** stuff yourself?

Comment: sorry I will try it myself first ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you are reading from file, you can use

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
scan.useDelimiter("\\Z");
String content = scan.next();
```

If you are taking input from a `console` you can use any other `delimiter` to end the reading.

Comment: Both of the answers worked well. Thank you for the reply.